# {% %} tags in django templates

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

I was going through the django docs and found this code in the template,

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

So could someone please explain what the `{% %}` tag stands for. Is it like `<? ?>` tag in php and if so why not add a single tag and print the rest of the html code?